# How do i apply 'React' in my web project only partionly? like jquery, vue :)

Tags: reactjs

I want to change only part of the project to `React`

Is there any way I can use React so flexible?

Comment: This is a pretty common question people have with both React and React Native. The answer is sometimes quite involved, but is explained very well over at [react armory](https://reactarmory.com/answers/how-to-integrate-react-into-existing-app)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is 'yes'.

You can render a React app of any size into any DOM element, regardless of whatever else you have in the DOM. The React docs [are really friendly](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html).